# How to get a property of an activeRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have this model

```
class Contestcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :used

  def self.is_valid(code)
    valid = false
    contestcode = Contestcode.where('code = ?', code)
    Rails.logger.debug("My object: #{contestcode.inspect}");
    if (contestcode)
      valid = contestcode.used
    end
    valid
  end
end
```

When I try to run `self.is_valid` I get this error:

```
undefined method `used' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ff525fde1a8>
```

The output of the debug statement is:

```
My object: [#<Contestcode id: 1, code: "aaaaa", used: false, created_at: "2013-01-23 10:21:32", updated_at: "2013-01-23 10:21:32">]
```

How can I get the used property of contestcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contestcode.where` returns a collection of Contestcodes. In your case, the `code` you are searching for is (hopefully!) unique, so it will be a collection of 1 item if it was found or 0 items if it was not.

You can see this in your debug statement - notice the square brackets around your object, which indicate that it's in an array (actually, an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which allows you to chain queries together, but it mostly behaves like an array).

What you really want here is `Contestcode.where(...).first`, which will extract the Contestcode from the array if it was found, or return `nil` if it was not.